# Sending POST request with multiples values for same key with requests library

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

How would you go about sending a request with multiples values with the same key?

```
r = requests.post('http://www.httpbin.org/post', data={1: [2, 3]})
print r.content
```

```
{
  ...
  "form": {
    "1": "3"
  }, 
  ...
}
```

**Edit:**

Hmm, very odd. I tried echoing the post data using a simple Flask application and I'm getting:

```
[('1', u'2'), ('1', u'3')]
```

Is this just a shortcoming of httpbin.org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that `requests` was sending the POST data without a problem. It was an issue on the http://httpbin.org end that was causing form data to be flattened, and multiple values with the same key to be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Try the Werkzeug `MultiDict`.  It's the same structure used for this purpose in Flask applications.

```
import requests
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

data = MultiDict([('1', '2'), ('1', '3')])
r = requests.post('http://www.httpbin.org/post', data=data)
print(r.content)
```

Result:

```
...
"form": {
  "1": [
    "2",
    "3"
  ]
},
...
```